# How to proper initialize the nvelocity engine?

Tags: .net, velocity, nvelocity

As I saw in some examples, and tried to understand throughout the [velocity site](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/app/VelocityEngine.html), there are three ways of initializing the velocityengine:
- With the default configurations : ***.Init()***
- With the default configurations, plus the properties in a file : ***.Init(string)***
- With the default configurations, plus the properties in a collection : ***.Init(Commons.Collections.ExtendedProperties)***

But i've found little explanation on how these work. Per example, in a app i've downloaded:

```
VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine();
ExtendedProperties props = new ExtendedProperties();
props.AddProperty("file.resource.loader.path", new ArrayList(new string[] { ".", @".\Templates" }));
engine.Init(props);
```

Beyond the obvious assumption, what is "**file.resource.loader.path**"?
What are the other properties i can change, and how can i change them (I mean, using the addproperty, or if there other ways please, specify)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#Velocity_Configuration_Keys_and_Values) is a list of available properties.